# can't make code generator with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, bitnami, yii

i have a problem in using code generator with PostgreSQL database, i've make configuration in main.php..
...

```
'modules'=>array(

    'gii'=>array(
        'class'=>'system.gii.GiiModule',
        'password'=>'123wasis85',
        'ipFilters'=>array('127.0.0.1','::1'),
    ),

),
```

...

```
'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'pgsql:host=127.0.0.1;port=5432;dbname=yii_first',

            'emulatePrepare' => true,

            'username' => 'postgres',

            'password' => 'anghauz',

            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
```

...

but it still making error result when i used crud generation, this is the error..:

...

```
CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection: could not find driver

C:\BitNami\apache2\htdocs\yii\framework\gii\generators\crud\CrudCode.php(44)
```

...

i make it in localhost n using bitnami..

please help me guys for the solutions..

Comment: So do you have the relevant PostgreSQL driver for php/yii installed? Oh, and it's Postgres or PostgreSQL never "Postgre".

Answer (score 3):

Please go to php.ini file in the installed php folder. Uncomment the below lines.

```
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pgsql.dll
```

It worked for me.